CSS table-layout auto with individual column deviations
I have a simple HTML table with table-layout set to auto. This table has some regular data columns and at last a special action column, i.e. a column with some buttons inside.
I now want my table to simply divide up the available space to all columns equally EXCEPT for the last column. I want this action column to take up the least available space required, all remaining space can just be divided equally among the remaining tables.
But I have not been able to achieve this. I cannot work with a fixed with for this action column, the number of buttons is unknown upfront. I just need it to make it take the least available automatically, not by defining an explicit width.
Below is a minimal reproducible example. It has 4 columns (3+1). The desired result is that the last one should be as small as possible.


table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: auto;
  /* wether it be 'auto' or 'fixed', last column should not be larger than necessary */
}

tr {
  text-align: left;
}

th:last-of-type {
  max-width: max-content;
  background-color: orange;
}

td:last-of-type {
  background-color: yellow;
  max-width: max-content;
  /* Does not work */
}
<table>
  <tr>
    <th> Header 1 </th>
    <th> Header 2 </th>
    <th> Header 3 </th>
    <th> Actions </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Data1_1 </td>
    <td> Data1_2 </td>
    <td> Data1_3 </td>
    <td>
      <button>Button 1</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Data2_1 </td>
    <td> Data2_2 </td>
    <td> Data2_3 </td>
    <td>
      <button>Button 1 </button>
      <button>Button 2</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>




Please show a proper [mre] of what you currently have.

@CBroe I included a sandbox. The idea behind it is really just as in the question. One column should not be auto-sized, but minimally-sized

@Sean thanks for the suggestion, I migrated the third party's code to a stack snippet

Could you describe more exactly what is required. I see you must keep table, and I’m sure you have to because it looks like tabular data anyway. However, what do you mean by minimal size for the last column? For example should you get as many buttons as possible on one line,or should they be stacked vertically right away so as to take up minimum width or….

@AHaworth we do not know upfront the number of buttons we will have in the action column, but it will generally be anywhere from 1 to 5 buttons. We would like to keep each record on a single line whenever possible, this includes the buttons. If there  are indeed 5 buttons then we want them all 5 next to one another, no vertical stacking. In our real scenario, these buttons are actually icon buttons so they will not take that much space anyways.

As @Paulie_D has pointed out, you will need JS for this. Is using JS possible in your context? If so please add javascript to the tags.

@AHaworth using JS is technically possible although I'd rather not. It looks very weird to me that we cannot specify a column width to fit its content

CSS-Grid/subgrid can do that rather than a table.
Keeping essentially the same structure but swapping out for div and span elements.


.wrap {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr) auto;
  background: orange;
  gap: .25em;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: subgrid;
  grid-column: 1 /-1;
}

span {
  padding: .25em;
  outline: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: lightgreen;
}

button {
  margin-right: .25em;
}

div {
  background: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: .25em;
}
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="row">
    <span> Header 1 </span>
    <span> Header 2 </span>
    <span> Header 3 </span>
    <span> Actions </span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span> Data1_1 </span>
    <span> Data1_2 </span>
    <span> Data1_3 </span>
    <span> 
      <button>Button 1</button> 
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span> Data2_1 </span>
    <span> Data2_2 </span>
    <span> Data2_3 </span>
    <span>
      <button>Button 1 </button>
      <button>Button 2</button>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>




Unfortunately that would not work for our project. The sample I provided was to offer a minimalistic reproducible one to illustrate my question. The real use case is far far far more complex than this. We are using a third party component provider in our Angular application. We HAVE to use HTML table.

Then you are stuck with table properties which do not permit a CSS-solution. You will need Javascript.

@Paulie_D There's no reason these styles can't be applied to table elements



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    table {
      width: 100%;
      table-layout: auto;
      /* wether it be 'auto' or 'fixed', last column should not be larger than necessary */
    }

    tr {
      text-align: left;
    }

    th:last-of-type {
      max-width: max-content;
      background-color: orange;
    }

    td:last-of-type {
      background-color: yellow;
      max-width: max-content;
      /* Does not work */
    }

    .action-column {
      width: 25%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th> Header 1 </th>
      <th> Header 2 </th>
      <th> Header 3 </th>
      <th class="action-column"> Actions </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Data1_1 </td>
      <td> Data1_2 </td>
      <td> Data1_3 </td>
      <td>
        <button>Button 1</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Data2_1 </td>
      <td> Data2_2 </td>
      <td> Data2_3 </td>
      <td>
        <button>Button 1 </button>
        <button>Button 2</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>



One way to achieve your required functionality is by setting the width of the last column so that it occupy only that space. **
Changes Made: I just assigned the last column in first row a specific width of 25%.
If you still have any queries. Feel free to comment down on this post

How do we know that 25% is the correct width - given the requirement is for the last column to be the smallest width it can be but that it may contain any number of buttons?

then you can set the min-width and max-width to particular values such that the last column will expand or shrink between these
